# How to do nested link scraping using BeautifulSoup and requests

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to **scrape** the texts of all of the episodes of all of the TV Series in a webpage. The entire thing is nested hence it goes through 3 webpages before finding the list of links.It is showing some error which I have pasted below.

```
 import requests
 import bs4 as bs

urls='http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/'
url=requests.get(urls).text
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')
title=soup.find_all('a')
ur=[""]

 
names=[""]
season=[""]
quality=[""]
for i in title:
   # names.append(i.text)
    urlss=urls+i.text+"/"
    urla=requests.get(urls).text
    soupp=bs.BeautifulSoup(urla,'lxml')
    ur=soupp.find_all('a')

    for i in ur:
    # names.append(i.text)
     urls=urls+i.text+"/"
     urla=requests.get(urls).text
     soupp=bs.BeautifulSoup(urla,'lxml')
     ur=soupp.find_all('a')

     for i in ur:
        # quality.append(i.text)
         urls=urls+i.text+"/"
         urla=requests.get(urls).text
         soupp=bs.BeautifulSoup(urla,'lxml')
         ur=soupp.find_all('a')

         for i in ur:
             print(i.text)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vedant Mamgain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Vedant Mamgain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Vedant Mamgain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Vedant Mamgain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Vedant Mamgain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Vedant Mamgain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 257, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Vedant Mamgain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Please make use of meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this, it worked for me:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
names = list()
name_links = list()
base_url = 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/'
final_list = list()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url).text, 'lxml')
title = soup.find_all('a')
for link in title[1:]:
    names.append(link.text)
    current_link = link['href']
    print(link.text)
    name_links.append(str(current_link))

    # get seasons
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url + current_link).text, 'lxml')
    title = soup.find_all('a')
    for link in title[1:]:
        season_link = link['href']

        # get quality of the seasons
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url + current_link +season_link).text, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find_all('a')
        for link in title[1:]:
            quality_link = link['href']

            # get list of episodes
            soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url + current_link + season_link + quality_link).text, 'lxml')
            title = soup.find_all('a')
            for link in title[1:]:
                episode_link = link['href']
                final_list.a
```

Check if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

urls = 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/'
url = requests.get(urls).text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
title = soup.find_all('a')

for i in title:

    if(i.text != '../' and ".mp4" not in i.text):
        urll = urls+i.text
    # arr.append(i.text)
        urll1 = requests.get(urll).text
        soupp1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(urll1, 'lxml')
        season = soupp1.find_all('a')
        print(i.text)
        for j in season:

            if(j.text != '../'and ".mp4" not in j.text):

                urlla = urll+j.text
                urll2 = requests.get(urlla).text
                soupp2 = bs.BeautifulSoup(urll2, 'lxml')
                quality = soupp2.find_all('a')
                print(j.text)
                for k in quality:
                    if(k.text != '../' and ".mp4" not in k.text):

                        urllb = urlla+k.text
                        urll3 = requests.get(urllb).text
                        soupp3 = bs.BeautifulSoup(urll3, 'lxml')
                        episode = soupp3.find_all('a')
                        print(k.text)
                        for m in episode:
                            if(m.text != '../' and ".mp4" not in m.text):
                                print(m.text)
```

I have solved the problem myself as well.Thanks to everyone who helped.